# API get запрос Axios, ошибка 401 (авторизация)

Tags: api, запрос, request, axios

Вкратце обрисую проблему: У меня есть 2 селектора (1. Марка авто 2.Модель авто), при загрузке страницы я получаю в первый селектор Марки авто (с помощью API запроса на PHP), при выборе определенной марки из селектора, мне необходимо получить во 2м селекторе модели этой марки, для реализации этого вопроса я использую реактивность Vue и Axios запрос (только я еще не особо дружу с этими ребятами:)). В моем коде, я покажу, как я получаю марку авто на PHP, было бы хорошо узнать, как я могу сделать подобное на js.

```html
$login = '111@yandex.ru'; 
$pass = '111';
$time = time(); 
$age = 60*60*24; 
$hash = md5($login.':'.$time.':'.$age.':'.hash('sha256', md5($pass))); 
$token = base64_encode(implode(':', [hash('sha256', $login), $time, $age, $hash])); 

$remote_url = 'https://api.inguru.ru/eosago/4.0/?q=list_brands';

        $opts = array(
            'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header' => "Authorization: INGURU " . $token
            )
        );
```

Второй вариант, это все что у меня есть из запроса Axios. Я так понимаю, мне необходимо правильно написать header, но вот в чем незадача, как видно из первого примера (PHP), мне необходимо сгенерировать $token. В общем, мне в принципе нужен просто какой то метод-пример на axios, где используется header ну и вообще какие либо параметры. Спасибо большое заранее. Прошу прощения за нубовскую тему))

```html
axios.get('https://api.inguru.ru/eosago/4.0/?brand=' + encodeURIComponent(this.brand) + '&q=list_models')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо указать токен в header'e http-запроса, в axios'e есть несколько вариантов указания header'ов:

- в объектe options при вызове метода `{ headers: {} }` [request config](http://request-config)
- в свойствах по умолчанию `axios.defaults.headers = {}` [global axios defaults](https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults)
- при создании экземпляра axios'a с параметрами `axiosInstance = axios.create({ headers: {} })` [custom instance default](https://github.com/axios/axios#custom-instance-defaults)

В случае с `axios.get`, необходимо указать второй параметр объект - `options`.

Также в options можно указать query params

```js
axios.get('https://api.inguru.ru/eosago/4.0/', {
  params: {
    brand: this.brand,
    q: list_models,
  },
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'INGURU ' + token,
  },
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что надо.